# "Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::users() using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

My controller code:

```
public function addGroup(Request $request)
{
    $validator = UserValidations::validateGroups($request->all());

    if($validator->fails()) {
        return response(['status' => false, 'message' => 'Validation Errors', 'errors' => $validator->errors()->all()], 500);
    }

    try {

        $request->request->add(['created_by' => Auth::user()->id]);
        $group = $this->group->create($request->only($this->group->getModel()->fillable));

        if(!empty($request->get('group_members')))
        {
            $groupMembers = Group::where('id', $group->id);
            $groupMembers->users()->attach($request->get('group_members'));
        }


        return response(['status' => true, 'message' => 'Group added', 'data' => $group], 500);

    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        return response(['status' => false, 'message' => 'Validation Errors', 'errors' => $ex->getMessage()], 500);
    }
}
```

My Group Model where there is relationship

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Users\User', 'group_members');
}
```

My request parameter:

```
{
    "name": "CM",
    "group_members": [74,75]
}
```

I want to assign group name with group members (users) and creating group name as well but I am getting error of `Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::users()`

Where I am going wrong?

Comment: You forgot the `get()` on your group call: `$groupMembers = Group::where('id', $group->id)->get();`

Comment: when i use get() it says method users() does not exist

Comment: $groupMembers->users()->attach($request->get('group_members'));

Comment: What is the full message when you use get?

Answer (score 2):

You have to get the group in this way :

```
$groupMembers = Group::where('id', $group->id)->first();
```

To be able to attach `Users` to a `Group`, you first need to get the instance with `first()`. You cant call `attach()` on a `Query\Builder`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Could you explain a bit what that does exactly?  Why is that the correct answer?